# Flutter: How can I parse the "title" data in the HTML attribute and display it in ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart, html-parsing

I have a trouble parsing and filtering the HTML data I need. I got close to the data by CSS selector, but when I print the filtered data in ListView, it shows only "" in a ListView. I used Dio to get the HTML source, and html API (not dart:html)to parse and filter the data. How can I parse the "title" data in the HTML attribute using Flutter and display it in listview? I really appreciate your help. Thank You.

This is the Flutter code where I parsed the data, and codes with comments are the codes I've already tried.

```
    setState(() {
      document = parse(response.data);
      //elements = document.getElementsByClassName('samu');
      //elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
      elements = document.querySelectorAll("td.subject > a.samu");
      //elements = elements.toString();
    });
  }
```

This is the code how I created Listview

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('크롤링 리스트'),
        ),
        body:
            //Text(_text));
            ListView.builder(
          itemCount: elements.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('${elements[index]}'),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
```

This is the HTML code that I want to parse. I want to filter(or get) data on the "title" section. In the HTML source I use, there is many datas useless data using "title", but all the data I need is associated within the class "samu".

```
       <td class="subject"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="samu" onclick="fnView('BBSMSTR_000000012758', '19151090'); " title="title 1">
                title 1</a>
```

Comment: Do you get this html code from elements[index] in the form of string?

Comment: I get it by DIO, and I can convert it to the form of string if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the `title` before parsing the html.
Assuming that the `response.data` returns a list of `<td>....</td>` html. You have to iterate on every `<td>...</td>` and extract the title.

For example,
Let's assume you get the list as follows:

```
"data": [
    "<td>...</td>",
    "<td>...</td>",
    ...
    "<td>...</td>",
]
```

Just iterate on every single element & extract the title using the below `getTitle` method.

```
String getTitle(String html) {
  // html = '''<td class="subject"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="samu" onclick="fnView('BBSMSTR_000000012758', '19151090'); " title="title 1">
  //          title 1</a>'''
  if(html.contains('title=')) {
    html = html.substring(html.indexOf('title='));
    html = html.substring(6, html.indexOf('>'));
    html = html.replaceAll('"', '');
    print(html); // Prints title 1
  }
  return html;
}
```

Comment: I really want to thank you for your sincere solution, but I have some quesitions unsolved. In this process, I have to parse multiple 'title' datas and there are some  'title' datas in that response AJAX that is useless. How can I filter useless datas and extract multiple datas? The datas I need in this response file is under "samu" class. And do you know if there is any way to extract the "title" data after it is queried by "document.querySelectorAll"?

Comment: I guess by "useless" you mean empty or `null` strings? If that is the case, we will have to store the `title` in a list & remove the useless `title` from it. Also, it will be really helpful if you paste the data that you get from `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: I see... Thank you so much for you help.

Comment: Welcome, buddy. You can upvote or accept the answer so that other users will understand that this answer was helpful to you.

Comment: Hello. I accepted your answer, but I can't up vote you because of my reputation. Sorry for that.